# How to configure path to files generated by Sencha CMD in index page

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, extjs, sencha-cmd, sencha-cmd5

I configured [sencha cmd](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/) in Maven using mojo plugin. My skeleton project is available [here](https://github.com/yurrrabilash/IVehicle). Project structure looks like below:

[image: project structure]

The `application` is the top-level folder of ExtJS application. The `/webapp/build/testing/IVehicle` is the destination folder for files generated by sencha cmd. `index.jsp` file contains the reference to the `app.json` looks: `Ext.manifest=Ext.manifest||"app.json";`. When i make a request to the `index.jsp` in browser i get the error `404`, because browser can't find `app.json` file in `webapp` folder(it's the root web folder). How i can configure sencha cmd to make path in `index.jsp` look like below: `Ext.manifest=Ext.manifest||"/build/testing/IVehicle/app.json";` ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your index.jsp, before microloader

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Ext = Ext || {};
Ext.manifest = 'foo';  // loads "./foo.json" relative to your page
</script>
```

See [Sencha Cmd Guide:Named Manifest](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/microloader.html#Named_Manifest)